# after adding data-ajax="false" back button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I have suppose two html files as index.html and test.html.  In index.html I have one button on click of that button I call test.html. In test.html I am displaying a table.  Now my index.html is like:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="d">

        <div data-role="header" align="center">

            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
                <h1>MySite.com</h1>
            <a href="MainMenu.html"  data-icon="grid">Menu</a>


        </div>
    <div data-role="content" >

        <a href="UI/Equal/test.html" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" id="myButton">i ndex</a>          



    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="UI/Equal/test.html"  data-ajax="false"> Order Book </a></li>
    </ul>

     </div>
</div>
```

Now onclick of button and on list I go to test.html, and table is displayed correctly. In my test.html there is a header and in that I have back button as:

```
<div data-role="header" align="center">

        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
            <h1>Test.com</h1>
        <a href="MainMenu.html"  data-icon="grid">Menu</a>


    </div>
```

Now when I click on back button It does not go to index.html. If I remove `data-ajax="false"` from index.html then back button of test.html works fine, but now in test.html I am using .css file for my table and here now effect of that .css file is not applied. IF I use `data-ajax="false"` in index.html then on Test.html table is properly drawn (means my .css file load correctly).  How I can get proper back button and table at same time.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `data-jax="false"` you are disabling jquery mobile's Ajax navigation, therefore the page you are linking to does not have access to the previous page in the DOM.

To have the back button on the second page, you need to hard-code it into the header, using a traditional `<a href="..."` link, or code it to pull the previous page from your DOM.